# Apache Commons FTP not writing to FileOutputStream with no error thrown

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons

I am using the apache commons library in an android app that we have developed.  This is legacy code, and for some reason, it is not writing to the device.  This is happening on multiple devices, so it's not device specific.  We are using Nexus 7 devices running Android 4.4.

The routine basically FTPs to our server and looks for new images to download.  FTP into server is successful, no problems there.

```
String listOfFiles = "GE_PT17_image.png,GE_PT18_image.png,GE_PT39_image.png";
String devicePathName = "/mnt/sdcard/company_name/DRMHH/"
status = ftpConnect(args[2], args[0], args[1], 21);
mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(pathname);

FTPFile[] files = mFTPClient.listFiles();
```

We basically look at all the images in the directory on the server, then match them to the desired images:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                            ;

    } else {
    ///mnt/sdcard/company_name/DRMHH/

   if (listOfFiles.toUpperCase().contains(files[i].getName().toUpperCase())) {
        File file = new File(devicePathName + File.separator + files[i].getName());
        Log.d("FileName", devicePathName + File.separator + files[i].getName());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); //NO ERROR or EXCEPTION
            boolean weAreOK = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(files[i].getName(), fos); //returns true
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("File Exception", e.toString());
        }

    }
  }

 }
```

No files are found on the device that were supposedly downloaded.  The variable returning whether file was successfully retrieved returns true.  Like I said, this is legacy code that has been around for years and until now worked with no problems.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "No files are found on the device that were supposedly downloaded" -- how are you determining this? You're not using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`, so these files will not show up via a USB connection for some time. If you cannot find them using **`adb`**, try calling `getFD().sync()` on `fos` after `flush()` and before `close()`. And I don't know where you are getting the value of `args[4]` from, but if that's not from a method on `Context` or `Environment` (e.g., it's hard-coded), that too could be a source of trouble.

Comment: I am using a USB connection to the device.  I've never had to wait for files until they showed up before.

Comment: I edited the value of the arg[4] - it's right when I debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol used over the USB connection, since Android 3.0, is the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP). The files served by Android over MTP are *not* what is on the filesystem, but rather what is indexed by the `MediaStore`.

Files that you create on external storage will eventually be indexed and added to the `MediaStore`. The key word is "eventually".

So, that means three things:

1. Please call `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream` after `flush()` and before `close()`. This ensures that the files are written to disk before continuing.
2. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` after `close()`, to tell `MediaStore` about the newly-created file, rather than waiting for the file to be indexed automatically at some arbitrary time in the future.
3. If you continue having problems, double check using DDMS's file explorer or **`adb shell`** whether the files are there, rather than relying solely on MTP.

Comment: Yes, checking via adb showed that the images were indeed on the device.  Thanks so much for your thoughtful answer.  +1

Comment: @KristyWelsh: Another wrinkle is the MTP client software on your development machine. The MTP protocol assumes that the device is not creating new files. As a result, there does not appear to be any means in MTP for Android to tell the desktop OS "hey, um, could you update your directory listing?". You may need to do some sort of "refresh" in your desktop file manager, or even unplug and re-plug-in the USB cable, to get the files to show up. That's not Android's fault, strictly speaking, but just a limitation of MTP, AFAICT.